# Using SignalR Core in a WebAPI to push messages to clients. (using .Net Core 3.1)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr, .net-core-3.1, signalrcore

I try to use SignalR in a .NetCore 3.1 WEBApi to push notifications/messages to connected clients. I used a few hours reading about the topic, but still I miss bits and pieces to get it working. So far, in my WebAPI I have:

An empty hub class:

```
    public class PLHub : Hub
    {
    }
```

a Notify class with IHubContext injection:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PadleloggAPI.Controllers
{
    public class PLNotifier
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<PLHub> mPLHubContext;

        public PLNotifier(IHubContext<PLHub> hubContext)
        {
            mPLHubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public async Task Notify(string user, string message)
        {
            await mPLHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

    }
}
```

In my Startup class I have:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<PLHub>("/PLHub");
            });
```

In my ConfigureServices I have:

```
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddSingleton<PLHub>();
```

What I'm missing is what to write in my api controller class to send the notification:

```
        // POST: api/Logg
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<LoggInstans>> PostLoggInstans(LoggInstans loggInstans)
        {
            _context.PadleLogg.Add(loggInstans);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            // HERE I WANT TO SEND MY NOTIFICATION TO ALL CLIENTS BUT HOW???

            return CreatedAtAction("GetLoggInstans", new { id = loggInstans.Id }, loggInstans);
        }
```

I'm not sure I have understood the concept completely, so there might very well besomthing else wrong in my code.

Comment: What notifications/messages do you want to push?If you just do not know how to call the `Notify`.Just DI the `PLNotifier` in your controller and call like below:`await _service.Notify("Username", "Data Update");`.Don't forget to register `PLNotifier` in your Startup.cs.

Comment: Thank you Rena, my question was that simple, but DI and SignalR are both new to me, so for that reason i could not get this right on my own. Registration of PLNotifier, and the dependensy injection was what I needed.